# How to ignore python UserWarning in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest, openpyxl, user-warning

I am using openpyxl for parsing .xlsm files, and pytest for testing.

When I open a file, I get the:
OpenPyxl -> UserWarning: Data Validation extension is not supported and will be removed

That is not really a problem bcs. program works and I can't change the .xlsm file to fix that.

But... 
When I run pytest with something like:

```
def test_wrong_file_format():  
    assert check_excel(open_excel('file.xlsm')) == True
```

I will get the warning i mentioned altought check_excel(open_excel('file.xlsm')) returns True and the test should suceed...

Is there a nice way to tell the pytest that "It's not a bug it's a feature" and tests should pass even when they get this warning?

Is there other way than using something like:

```
with pytest.warns(UserWarning):
    warnings.warn("my warning", UserWarning)
```

Thank you,
Tom

Comment: `pytest -W ignore::UserWarning`. Or persist it in `pytest.cfg` to not to enter it each time: `filterwarnings = ignore::UserWarning`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documentation ([pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html)),
`@pytest.mark.filterwarnings` is the right approach.
Just choose the correct params, for example:

```
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings('ignore::UserWarning')
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.  
the correct syntax is:  
`@pytest.mark.filterwarnings('ignore::UserWarning')`